# Django url dispatcher page not found

Tags: django, django-urls

i am trying to define a url pattern in django urls.py like

```
 url(r'^networking$','mysite1.networking.views.networking'),
```

when i am typing  http://myhost.com/networking in my address bar to go to networking page

i am getting 404 error and a slash '/' automatically added to the address bar like

http://myhost.com/networking/

help me out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably aren't including your urlconf correctly.  The behavior you're seeing is because of  [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) is set to True by default when Django can't resolve the url.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Apache server or some Django middleware is adding trailing slashes. You can either correct that, or the better way is you can use the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^networking/?$','mysite1.networking.views.networking'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set Append_Slash to false which is true by default or use your url description like given below which redirect url with slash to desired view.

url(r'^networking/$','mysite1.networking.views.networking'),

Comment: networking/ will accept only /networking/ and not /networking

Comment: @vivek if i am using  (r'^networking/?$', include('mysite1.networking.urls')),   in that case when i am trying http://127.0.0.1:8000/networking/multiwanrule  in networking.urls.py it is again showing 404 error   second url pattern is like  url(r'^multiwanrule/',multiwanrule_info),

Comment: Yeah, You nedd to add '/?' to all your url patterns to accept requests with and without slash. better uncomment APPEND_SLASH.